# Serializing Eigen vectors to QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I'm trying to serialize Eigen vectors to `QDataStream`:

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "Eigen/Eigen"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Eigen::Vector3d>("Eigen::Vector3d");

    Eigen::Vector3d vec(9, 4, 5);

    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    ds << vec;

    Eigen::Vector3d vv;
    ds >> vv;
    qDebug() << vv[1];

    return a.exec();
}
```

utils.cpp

```
#pragma once

#include "utils.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Eigen::Vector3d)

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Eigen::Vector3d &v)
{
    out << v[0] << v[1] << v[2];
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Eigen::Vector3d &v)
{
    in >> v[0] >> v[1] >> v[2];
    return in;
}
```

The problem is that main prints 0, so I guess I'm not doing the serialization right. |So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK, except that you never read anything back, because a `QIODevice` has only one read-write position. You need to rewind the device back to the start. There is plenty of unnecessary code that I guess you tried out of desperation.

Instead of saying in English what is printed out as debug output, it's much better to say it in code using `Q_ASSERT`: that leaves nothing to interpretation.

The below reproduces your problem, and demonstrates the solution. It also extends the data stream support to all constant-sized matrices.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

template <typename T, int R, int C>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Eigen::Matrix<T, R, C> &m) {
   Q_STATIC_ASSERT(R != Eigen::Dynamic && C != Eigen::Dynamic);
   for (int i = 0; i < R; i ++)
      for (int j = 0; j < C; j ++)
         out << m(i, j);
   return out;
}

template <typename T, int R, int C>
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Eigen::Matrix<T, R, C> &m) {
   Q_STATIC_ASSERT(R != Eigen::Dynamic && C != Eigen::Dynamic);
   for (int i = 0; i < R; i ++)
      for (int j = 0; j < C; j ++)
         in >> m(i, j);
   return in;
}

int main() {
   QByteArray data;
   QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

   Eigen::Vector3d const v1(9, 4, 5);
   ds << v1;

   Eigen::Vector3d v2;
   ds >> v2;
   Q_ASSERT(v2 != v1);
   Q_ASSERT(ds.status() != QDataStream::Ok);

   ds.device()->seek(0);
   ds >> v2;
   Q_ASSERT(v1 == v2);
}
```

A complete solution would handle interoperation between integer, floating point and complex data types of arbitrary sizes:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/eigen-stream-50905799
#include <QtCore>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <type_traits>
```

#### Implementation

```
namespace detail {
enum EigenType : quint8 {
   Double =     0x00,
   CDouble =    0x01,
   ScalarMask = 0x0F,
   Vector =     0x40,   // d x 1
   RowVector =  0x80,   // 1 x d
   Matrix =     0xC0,   // d x d
   StructureMask = 0xC0
};

template <typename T> void dumpElement(QDataStream &out, T el)
{ out << (double)el; }

template <typename T> void dumpElement(QDataStream &out, const std::complex<T> &el)
{ out << (double)el.real() << (double)el.imag(); }

template <typename T> void readDouble(QDataStream &in, T &el)
{ double v; in >> v; el = v; }

template <typename T> void readDouble(QDataStream &in, std::complex<T> &el)
{ double v; in >> v; el.real(v); el.imag(0); }

template <typename T> void readComplex(QDataStream &in, T &el)
{ double re, im; in >> re >> im; el = re; }

template <typename T> void readComplex(QDataStream &in, std::complex<T> &el)
{ double re, im; in >> re >> im; el.real(re); el.imag(im); }
} // namespace detail

template <typename D>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Eigen::MatrixBase<D> &m) {
   quint8 type = 0;
   if (std::is_integral<typename D::Scalar>::value ||
       std::is_floating_point<typename D::Scalar>::value)
      type = detail::Double;
   else if (std::is_same<std::complex<float>, typename D::Scalar>::value ||
            std::is_same<std::complex<double>, typename D::Scalar>::value)
      type = detail::CDouble;
   else {
      out.setStatus(QDataStream::WriteFailed);
      return out;
   }
   if (m.cols() == 1)
      out << (type |= detail::Vector) << (quint32)m.rows();
   else if (m.rows() == 1)
      out << (type |= detail::RowVector) << (quint32)m.cols();
   else
      out << (type |= detail::Matrix) << (quint32)m.rows() << (quint32)m.cols();

   for (int i = 0; i < m.rows(); i ++)
      for (int j = 0; j < m.cols(); j ++)
         detail::dumpElement(out, m(i, j));
   return out;
}

template <typename D>
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Eigen::MatrixBase<D> &m) {
   using std::swap;
   quint8 type;
   quint32 rows, cols;
   in >> type;
   if (in.status() != QDataStream::Ok)
      return in;
   bool const complex = (type & detail::ScalarMask) == detail::CDouble;
   quint8 t = type & detail::StructureMask;
   if (t == detail::Vector) {
      cols = 1;
      in >> rows;
   }
   else if (t == detail::RowVector) {
      rows = 1;
      in >> cols;
   }
   else if (t == detail::Matrix) {
      in >> rows >> cols;
   }
   else {
      in.setStatus(QDataStream::ReadCorruptData);
      return in;
   }
   if (in.status() != QDataStream::Ok)
      return in;
   if ((rows == 1 && m.ColsAtCompileTime == 1) || (cols == 1 && m.RowsAtCompileTime == 1))
      swap(rows, cols); // row- and column-vectors are interchangeable
   m.derived().resize(rows, cols);
   if (m.rows() == rows && m.cols() == cols) {
      if (!complex) {
         for (uint i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
            for (uint j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
               detail::readDouble(in, m(i, j));
      } else {
         for (uint i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
            for (uint j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
               detail::readComplex(in, m(i, j));
      }
   } else {
      double dummy;
      for (uint i = 0; i < (rows*cols*(complex ? 2 : 1)); ++i)
         in >> dummy;
   }
   return in;
}
```

#### Test Harness

```
template <typename T> QDebug operator<<(QDebug d, const std::complex<T> &c) {
   return d << c.real() << ";" << c.imag();
}

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Eigen::internal::cast_impl<std::complex<T1>, T2> {
   EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC static inline T2 run(const std::complex<T1> &x) { return x.real(); }
};

template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1, typename T3 = T1> void test() {
   QByteArray data;
   QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);

   using namespace Eigen;
   Matrix<T1,3,1> const v1 = Matrix<T3,3,1>::Random().template cast<T1>();
   Matrix<T1,1,3> const v2 = Matrix<T3,1,3>::Random().template cast<T1>();
   Matrix<T1,4,4> const m1 = Matrix<T3,4,4>::Random().template cast<T1>();
   Matrix<T1,Dynamic,Dynamic> const m2 = Matrix<T3,Dynamic,Dynamic>::Random(4, 4).template cast<T1>();
   Matrix<T1,Dynamic,Dynamic> const m3 = Matrix<T3,Dynamic,Dynamic>::Random(2, 5).template cast<T1>();
   ds << v1 << v1 << v2 << v2 << m1 << m1 << m2 << m2 << m3;

   Matrix<T2,3,1> iv3 = Matrix<T2,3,1>::Random();
   Matrix<T2,1,3> irv3;
   Matrix<T2,4,4> im4;
   Matrix<T2,Dynamic,Dynamic> imX;
   ds >> iv3;
   Q_ASSERT(iv3.template cast<T3>() != v1.template cast<T3>());
   Q_ASSERT(ds.status() != QDataStream::Ok);

   ds.device()->reset();
   ds.resetStatus();
   Q_ASSERT(ds.status() == QDataStream::Ok);
   ds >> iv3 >> irv3;
   Q_ASSERT(ds.status() == QDataStream::Ok);
   Q_ASSERT(iv3.template cast<T3>() == v1.template cast<T3>());
   Q_ASSERT((irv3.template cast<T3>() == Eigen::Matrix<T3,1,3>(v1.template cast<T3>())));
   ds >> irv3 >> iv3;
   Q_ASSERT(irv3.template cast<T3>() == v2.template cast<T3>());
   Q_ASSERT((iv3.template cast<T3>() == Eigen::Matrix<T3,3,1>(v2.template cast<T3>())));

   ds >> im4 >> imX;
   Q_ASSERT(im4.template cast<T3>() == m1.template cast<T3>());
   Q_ASSERT(imX.template cast<T3>() == m1.template cast<T3>());
   ds >> im4 >> imX;
   Q_ASSERT(im4.template cast<T3>() == m2.template cast<T3>());
   Q_ASSERT(imX.template cast<T3>() == m2.template cast<T3>());
   ds >> imX;
   Q_ASSERT(imX.template cast<T3>() == m3.template cast<T3>());
}

int main() {
   test<int>();
   test<float>();
   test<double>();
   test<std::complex<float>>();
   test<std::complex<double>>();

   test<short, float>();
   test<float, short, short>();
   test<int, double>();
   test<double, int, int>();
   test<float, double>();
   test<double, float, float>();

   test<float, std::complex<float>>();
   test<float, std::complex<double>>();
   test<double, std::complex<float>, float>();
   test<double, std::complex<double>>();
   test<std::complex<float>, float, float>();
   test<std::complex<double>, float, float>();
   test<std::complex<float>, double, double>();
   test<std::complex<double>, double, double>();

   test<short, std::complex<float>>();
   test<std::complex<float>, short, short>();
   test<int, std::complex<double>>();
   test<std::complex<double>, int, int>();
}
```

Comment: Nice examples, thanks. And why cannot these templates work for dynamic matrices (`MatrixXd`)? What should I do here to accomplish this? (if it's too much for this question never mind, thanks anyway)

Comment: They couldn't work because they assume fixed sizes. For dynamic sizes, both ends of the chain need to be able to handle interoperation of not only varying sizes, but also types. It gets interesting then.